# I want to create <li> tags in single row using jquery or java script not using css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help on creating a item list from `<li>car<li>bus<li>cycle<li>aeroplane`

to a single line(row) instead of (column) like this

```
<li>car<li>bus<li>cycle<li>aeroplane
```

i do not want break on each list tag.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/88/)

Comment: Use CSS to give each of your `<li>` tags `float:left`, and they would aligned on one line.

Comment: Set `display: inline;` for `li`s

Comment: Unfortunately HTML is not rendered by javascript, its rendered by the browser and styled using css so no matter how you write it CSS is the only way to tell the browser what you want.

Comment: @JustinHerter is right. The only minor thing I'd mention is you can do it with JS (sort of) by using the `$.css` jquery function, but at that point you're still using CSS only you're applying it to the individual item as opposed to using a more encompassing CSS rule

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a JavaScript question, but a CSS question.  In order to display list items on a single line, you need to set the `li` elements display setting to `inline-block` or `inline`.

```css
.inline-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* border added to outline the fact they are inline */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="inline-list">
  <li>Planes</li>
  <li>Trains</li>
  <li>Automobiles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am creating list dynamically by using java script .its purely related to JavaScript. for further see my fiddle

Comment: Adding the elements dynamically: purely JS. Getting the elements in a single line (as your question and title are asking): *mostly* CSS (there are ways to do this with JS, but it makes more sense to do it with CSS)

Comment: i do not want to use display inline in<ul> tag

Comment: If you want LI tag items to be placed on a single row/line, you need some type of inline/inline-block display setting on the LI tags

Answer (score 0):

this should be a good starting point:

```
#grocery-list ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#grocery-list ul li:before{
    content:'\25CF'; 
    margin-right:0.5em;
}
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/97/)

Answer (score 0):

Disc style:

```css
li{
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Car</li>
  <li>Bus</li>
  <li>Cycle</li>
  <li>Plane</li>
</ul>
```